# How does iphone handle text messages/phone calls when a user is playing a multiplayer game

Tags: ios, iphone

I would like to know as to how the iphone handles these four possibilities when a user is playing a game. And also any more possibilities can be pointed out by you guys.

○ User receives a text message in the middle of a single player game

○ User receives a phone call in the middle of a multiplayer game and decides to
answer the call.

○ User closes the app with the home button in the middle of a single player game.

○ User presses the lock button while on the Main Menu of the application, outside of
a game.

Also what are the problems/issues I would  when developing code for this ?
If anybody could explain this diagrammatically it would be really helpful.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question, unless you want to know what happens behind the scenes. As to which methods are called. Plus this can easily be tested by yourself.

Comment: I dont have an iphone, And i am new to programming for iphone. I tried finding answers online. But did not get substantial ones. That is why i asked here. And you can see that i have asked what problems i will face when developing code for this. I am trying to build a multiplayer game. I want to know how different games and game engines handle it.

Answer (score 0):

This method is in your `AppDelegate.m`. This method gets called when the user quits the app, gets a phone call, or receives a text message:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}
```

Comment: Hi Abudullah, I am looking more in terms of UI. As to how the iphone handles it. And not in terms of code.